# Support IE 8 and IE Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I want to have my page load with support for IE8 and IE11. This means IE9 browsers should load the page as IE8, and IE11 should load as IE11. I have tried this with no success:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=9" />
```

Is this the right way to include this tag?

Comment: The `x-ua-compatible` header/tag is meant to cause old webpages to render better in modern browsers. Are you dealing with a page that was designed/built for IE 8?

Comment: Yes, the site was intended for use in IE19, but renders using IE8 mode

Comment: If it was designed with/for IE 9, you should use the x-ua-compatible meta tag instructing the content to render in IE 9 document mode. Keep in mind this is a *temporary* solution, just until you can make the site work properly in a modern version of IE. Then remove the x-ua-compatible meta tag.